# Counting where multiple street names within polygon using MapInfo?

Tags: sql, mapinfo, query, count

I have a dataset of address points with their associated street name, in addition to a tab file of polygons covering a catchment. I want to know if there is a way of selecting polygons which have address points with different street names within them.

I am guessing that there is a way of using the count function in MapInfo but unsure how this works with character fields.

Answer (score 1):

The MapBasic SQL dialect is rather restricted, but this is possible by using several temporary tables.
Assuming that the `Points` table has a column `StreetName`, and that the `Catchments` table has a unique `ID` value, these three SQL statements should work (enter them into the MapBasic window):

```
Select ID, StreetName 
   From Points, Catchments 
   Where Points.obj intersects Catchments.obj 
   Into temp noselect 
   Group By ID, StreetName
select ID, count(*) 
   from temp 
   into temp2 noselect 
   Group By ID
Select * 
   From Catchments 
   Where ID in (select ID from temp2 where count > 1)
```

Comment: I would use Within instead of Intersects as you are comparing points to polygons. But besides that, nice workaround for the limitations of the MapBasic SQL